# Plant pest detection using CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, opencv

I am doing a project in plant pest detection using CNN. There are four classes each having about 1400 images. While training the model using Convolution Neural Network, there is a smooth curve for training while for validation there lots of ups and downs in high range. After that,I start using alexnet architecture of CNN. There is smooth curve in both training and validation but overfitting problem occurs.What are the things I should consider for resolving this issues.Is there any other standard CNN architecture for training when there is small data. You can find the code in more detail [alexnet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4tCS.png)

```
EPOCHS = 20
INIT_LR = 1e-5
BS = 8
default_image_size = tuple((256, 256))
image_size = 0
directory_root = '../input/plantvillag/'
width=256
height=256
depth=3
```

**Function to convert images to array**

```
  def convert_image_to_array(image_dir):
        try:
            image = cv2.imread(image_dir)
            if image is not None :
                image = cv2.resize(image, default_image_size)   
                return img_to_array(image)
            else :
                return np.array([])
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error : {e}")
            return None
```

**Fetch images from directory**

```
image_list, label_list = [], []
    try:
        print("[INFO] Loading images ...")
        root_dir = listdir(directory_root)
        for directory in root_dir :
            # remove .DS_Store from list
            if directory == ".DS_Store" :
                root_dir.remove(directory)

    for plant_folder in root_dir :
        plant_disease_folder_list = listdir(f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}")

        for disease_folder in plant_disease_folder_list :
            # remove .DS_Store from list
            if disease_folder == ".DS_Store" :
                plant_disease_folder_list.remove(disease_folder)

        for plant_disease_folder in plant_disease_folder_list:
            print(f"[INFO] Processing {plant_disease_folder} ...")
            plant_disease_image_list = listdir(f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}/{plant_disease_folder}/")

            for single_plant_disease_image in plant_disease_image_list :
                if single_plant_disease_image == ".DS_Store" :
                    plant_disease_image_list.remove(single_plant_disease_image)

            for image in plant_disease_image_list[:1000]:
                image_directory = f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}/{plant_disease_folder}/{image}"
                if image_directory.endswith(".jpg") == True or image_directory.endswith(".JPG") == True:
                    image_list.append(convert_image_to_array(image_directory))
                    label_list.append(plant_disease_folder)
    print("[INFO] Image loading completed")  
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error : {e}")
```

**Get Size of Processed Image**

```
image_size = len(image_list)
```

**Transform Image Labels uisng Scikit Learn's LabelBinarizer**

```
    label_binarizer = LabelBinarizer()
image_labels = label_binarizer.fit_transform(label_list)
pickle.dump(label_binarizer,open('label_transform.pkl', 'wb'))
n_classes = len(label_binarizer.classes_)

    np_image_list = np.array(image_list, dtype=np.float32) / 255.0
```

**Splitting data**

```
print("[INFO] Spliting data to train, test")

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = 
train_test_split(np_image_list,image_labels, test_size=0.2, random_state = 42) 



aug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=25, width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, 
    zoom_range=0.2,horizontal_flip=True, 
    fill_mode="nearest")
```

**Model Build**

```
from keras import layers
from keras.models import Model

optss = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
def alexnet(in_shape=(256,256,3), n_classes=n_classes, opt=optss):
    in_layer = layers.Input(in_shape)
    conv1 = layers.Conv2D(96, 11, strides=4, activation='relu')(in_layer)
    pool1 = layers.MaxPool2D(3, 2)(conv1)
    conv2 = layers.Conv2D(256, 5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')(pool1)
    pool2 = layers.MaxPool2D(3, 2)(conv2)
    conv3 = layers.Conv2D(384, 3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')(pool2)
    conv4 = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')(conv3)
    pool3 = layers.MaxPool2D(3, 2)(conv4)
    flattened = layers.Flatten()(pool3)
    dense1 = layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu')(flattened)
    drop1 = layers.Dropout(0.8)(dense1)
    dense2 = layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu')(drop1)
    drop2 = layers.Dropout(0.8)(dense2)
    preds = layers.Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')(drop2)

    model = Model(in_layer, preds)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model


    model = alexnet()
```

**Performing Training**

```
    history = model.fit_generator(
    aug.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=BS),
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1
    )
```

**Graphs**

```
acc = history.history['acc']
val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
epochs = range(1, len(acc) + 1)
#Train and validation accuracy
plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'b', label='Training accurarcy')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'r', label='Validation accurarcy')
plt.title('Training and Validation accurarcy')
plt.legend()

plt.figure()
#Train and validation loss
plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'b', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'r', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and Validation loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Request for clarification: what language are your using?

Comment: I am using python

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! `I am using python` Use tags to direct attention with regard to (your) questions.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if the question is suited for Code Review. Since this is more of a general neural network question, and not really about improving the code quality, it might be better suited for [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).